# In Ubuntu 22.04, how to make a taskbar shortcut (with a certain icon) that runs a specific command when clicked?

Tags: .desktop, shortcuts, taskbar

In Ubuntu 22.04, how can I make a taskbar shortcut that uses `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/firefox.png` as an icon and runs `firefox --private-window` when clicked?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a file at `~/.local/share/applications/firefox-private.desktop`.
2. Paste these lines into the file, and save it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox Private
Exec=firefox --private-window
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/firefox.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
```

3. Make the file executable: `chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/firefox-private.desktop`
4. You *might* need to log out and back in.
5. Search for "Firefox Private" in Activities. To open the Activities search, you can either click Activities in the top left of your screen, or you can press the Windows key on your keyboard.
6. Right-click your new "Firefox Private" icon that appears in those search results.
7. Choose "Add to Favorites".
8. (You'll then see the icon in your taskbar.)